# how can i resize element while scrolling so as not to scroll the entire page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make similar animation on scroll like in first section of this site:
[link](https://kafeaterra.gr/).
I can't figure out how to resize the video element while scrolling so as not to scroll the entire page.
tried using wheel event listener instead of scroll but that didn't seem to work for me.

i am an absolute noob in such animations, so I would really appreciate any help

Comment: These sites usually use a library like [Locomotive Scroll](https://locomotivemtl.github.io/locomotive-scroll/) (because this stuff is hard to build). I'm not sure we can help you with building it all, though I would suggest starting small. The video is not "resizing", it's actually being clipped with the [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property, cutting out part of the video and exposing the background behind the video. You might want to start there.